# 2 Lists of Different Length used to Create 3rd List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have one list similar in structure to (letters would be data):

```
|A|B|C|D|E|F|G|
```

I also have another list similar to:

```
|A|B|E|G|
```

I want to create a 3rd list that is the same length as the first but places "NULL" in the columns that don't exist in the 2nd list, such as:

```
|A|B|NULL|NULL|E|NULL|G|
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something along the lines of:

```
var list1 = new List<string>() {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"};
var list2 = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "E","G" };
var list3 = new List<string>();
int j = 0;
for(int i=0; i < list1.Count; i++)
{
    var item = list1[i];
    if (item == list2[j])
    {
     list3.Add(item);
     j++;
    }
    else
    {
      list3.Add(null);
    }
 }
```

Comment: This assumes that the columns will appear in the same order, if they are present.  That may or may not be the OP's case (not clear to me from the question).

Comment: I know, but his example seemed to suggest that. And although I really like your answer, it uses contains. So I thought my answer would give some value too :P

Comment: My actual issue was a good deal more complex than my example above.  Your solution led me to the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use Linq:

```
var result = 
    firstList.Select(p => secondList.Contains(p) ? p : null).ToList();
```

If the lists are large, the fact that this is O(N^2) might matter.  You can improve performance if you can represent secondList as a HashSet instead, as set membership lookup for a HashSet is O(1).

Comment: I was working on something without the ? and so had to combine 2 lists. This is great.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate your first list, for each element compare it with the corresponding element in your second list, if theres a match output that, otherwise output a null, keep going until you reach the end of your first list.